# Explorer.exe запускается в виде проводника, а не графической оболочки

Tags: python, windows, vbscript

Если запустить скрипт, который убивает графическую оболчку windows (explorer.exe), а затем в этом же скрипте вызвать этот explorer.exe обратно, то он запустится в виде проводника, а не графической оболочки.

Если же ввести все то же самое вручную, то запускается граф. оболочка. Как решить проблему?

Код на vbs:

```
Do
set t = createobject("wscript.shell")
t.run"taskkill /f /im explorer.exe"
t.run"explorer.exe"
```

даже если указать полный путь до эксплорера или запустить от имени администратора, то он все равно будет запускаться как проводник.

Код на python: (тот же результат, не запускается как надо)

```
import os
os.system('taskkill /f /im explorer.exe')
os.system('explorer.exe')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данная проблема связана с тем, что вы запускаете explorer из 32-битного интерпретатора. Если вы запустите из 64-битного то ваши команды будут работать.

Либо можно напрямую прописать путь до 64-битной cmd, она находиться в папке sysnative. 
(когда вы обращаетесь без абсолютного пути, то по дефолту запускается cmd из C:\Windows\system32)

```
import os
os.system('taskkill /f /im explorer.exe')
os.system('%systemroot%\sysnative\cmd.exe /c start explorer.exe')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, если честно, уже больше чем полгода с этой проблемой живу, приходится постоянно вызывать диспетчер задач и вручную включать оболочку. Спасибо